# Call script from iptables?

Tags: bash, scripts, iptables

I try to Call script by iptables. The script it get ip address and send to my server.
 It maybe look like this.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <some_script.sh>
```

How can possible with that, Thank you very much.

Comment: `iptables` does not have the capacity to pass things to scripts.  You would need to pass it to a specific local IP/port pairing, and then that would have to pass it to a script or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you try to achieve is to use the output from your script in your iptables command.

You need to enclose your script in $() or `` like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $(<some_script.sh>)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination `<some_script.sh>`
```

In that way the output from your script will be used as the parameter in the iptables command.
You need to make sure your script will output an IP address. Something like `192.168.1.13`, because iptables expect an IP there.